# How to build Exponential Smoothing Model

Tags: r

My data :

```
library(forecast)
library(Mcomp)

# Time Series
# Subset the M3 data to contain the relevant series 
ts.data<- subset(M3, 12)[[551]]
print(ts.data)
```

I have selected time series 551 of the monthly data of the M3 competition.

I want to *build exponential smoothing model (ETS) and then calculate the in-sample error and out-of-sample error of the model*.

How can i get through this ? Any help?

EDITED !

My code :

```
# Exponential Smoothing Model

library(forecast)
library(Mcomp)

# My data is
# Time Series
# Subset the M3 data to contain the relevant series 
ts.data<- subset(M3, 12)[[551]]
print(ts.data)


library(tidyverse)
library(fpp2) 

# Holt’s Method

# create training and validation 
# of the data 
data.train <- window(???) 
data.test <- window(???)

holt.data <- holt(data.train, 
                  h = 100) 
autoplot(holt.data)

# holt's method 
holt.data$model 

# accuracy of the model 
accuracy(holt.data, data.test)

# try to find the optimal value of beta through a loop ranging from 0.0001 to 0.5 that will minimize the RMSE test
# identify optimal alpha parameter 
beta <- seq(.0001, .5, by = .001) 
RMSE <- NA
for(i in seq_along(beta)) { 
  fit <- holt(data.train, 
              beta = beta[i],  
              h = 100) 
  RMSE[i] <- accuracy(fit,  
                      data.test)[2,2] 
} 

# convert to a data frame and 
# idenitify min alpha value 
beta.fit <- data_frame(beta, RMSE) 
beta.min <- filter(beta.fit,  
                   RMSE == min(RMSE))

# plot RMSE vs. alpha 
ggplot(beta.fit, aes(beta, RMSE)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(data = beta.min,  
             aes(beta, RMSE),  
             size = 2, color = "red")


# Refit the model with the obtained optimal value of beta :
# Set the optimal value of beta nad also compare the predictive accuracy with our original model.

# new model with optimal beta 
holt.data.opt <- holt(data.train, 
                      h = 100, 
                      beta = 0.0601) 

# accuracy of first model 
accuracy(holt.data, data.test) 

# accuracy of new optimal model 
accuracy(holt.data.opt, data.test) 

p1 <- autoplot(holt.data) + 
  ggtitle("Original Holt's Model") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(400, 1000)) 

p2 <- autoplot(holt.data.opt) + 
  ggtitle("Optimal Holt's Model") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(400, 1000)) 

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2,  
                        nrow = 1)
```

**My problem is that i cant create my data.train and data.test samples.**

```
data.train <- window(???) 
data.test <- window(???)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Searching for `"r" exponential smoothing model` has several promising links. Your question seems a little vague at the moment, and sounds as if you are asking us to do homework for you. It's generally better to bring actual code to your question and ask us to help fix problems with it.

Comment: Here is my code @r2evans , my problem is in the data train and data test , i dont know what to include in my "window" function . Can you suggest me some solution ?

Comment: Check the Edited question ! @r2evans

Comment: Any ideas ?? @hello_friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this good stack [exchange answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44984/how-do-you-use-simple-exponential-smoothing-in-r) you could do :

```
library(forecast)
library(Mcomp)

# Time Series
# Subset the M3 data to contain the relevant series 
ts.data<- subset(M3, 12)[[551]]
ts.data

mod1 <- HoltWinters(ts.data$x, alpha=0.1, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
pred <- predict(mod1, n.ahead=30)

abs_error <- abs(pred - ts.data$xx)
mae <- sum(abs_error)/30
mae

# with forcats
mod2 <- forecast::ses(ts.data$x, h=30, alpha=0.1, initial="simple")
pred2 <- predict(mod2, n.ahead=30)

abs_error2 <- abs(pred2$mean - ts.data$xx)
mae2 <- sum(abs_error2)/30
mae2
```